# How to observe property changes with dom-bind

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

How to observe property changes if I use `dom-bind`? The change in property is updated inside curly brackets, so I assume that there is some event related to change, but I don't know it's name.

Example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="">
<head >
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
  <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <style>
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<template is="dom-bind" id="app2">
  <p>test: <span>{{test}}</span></p>
  <input type="button" value="Change" on-click="chTest">
</template>
<script>
  (function (document) {
    'use strict';
    var app = document.querySelector('#app2');
    app.test = "original value";

    app.addEventListener('test-changed', function () {
      console.log('change listener fired');
    });
    app.addEventListener('dom-change', function () {
      console.log("dom-change");
    });
    app.chTest = function () {
      console.log('click');
      app.test = "new value";
// notifyPath-setter will fire "test-changed"-event
//      app.notifyPath("test", "notify value");
    };
  })(document);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:
There is a need to clarify my question: I want to invoke some function, when app.test changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the answer commented out. Comment the line app.test and uncomment the app.notifyPath

```
//      app.test = "new value";
// notifyPath-setter will fire "test-changed"-event
      app.notifyPath("test", "notify value");
```

Working jsbin below:

http://jsbin.com/vaqosi/edit?html,console,output

Edit: One workaround is to two way bind it into a child element and listen for its changes. I have updated the jsbin.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't explain my example enough. NotifyPath was in the code just to test event listener ie. if notifyPath is used then test-changed listener will respond. My problem is how to listen the changes in app.test-property. I want to invoke some function, when app.test changes.

Comment: Got it. One work around is to two way bind the value to a child element and listen for its changes. I have updated the jsbin.

Comment: This seems to be the simplest solution at the moment. Basically you need to add a simple custom element (for example: <x-example child-test="{{test}}" on-child-test-changed="childTestChanged"></x-example>) into a dom-bind -template. The observed property is bound to the custom element and your change-function will trigger every time the property is changed.